# Loading Open Cycle Map on OSMdroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

Sorry I am new to Android development.
Wondering if there is any method to load Open Cycle Map using OSMdroid please?
From the website, seems there is no easy way to do so:
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources

Therefore, would any one can give me some tips how to do so please?

What I can think the only way is to define Tile Source manually as below.
Wondering if there is any easier way to do so please?

```
final String[] tileURLs = {"http://a.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/",
              "http://b.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/",                                              
               "http://c.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/"};

final ITileSource OCM =
        new XYTileSource("Open Cycle Map",
                            0,
                            19,
                            512,
                            ".png",
                            tileUrls,
                            "from open cycle map");
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a tile-source is a correct way how to do it. And it's a perfectly fine way, many build-in tile-sources are defined in the [same way](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/282046b69660eb715ac03374f36c19b993523951/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/tilesource/TileSourceFactory.java#L132).

However, according to the documentation at the http://thunderforest.com/maps/opencyclemap/ you should obtain and use API key:

> Want to use these tiles? The generic tile format string for the
>   OpenCycleMap layer is:
>
> `https://tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=<insert-your-apikey-here>`

Therefore you should include you API key:

```
final ITileSource OCM =
        new XYTileSource("Open Cycle Map",
                            0,
                            19,
                            512,
                            ".png?apikey=<insert-your-apikey-here>",
                            tileUrls,
                            "from open cycle map");
```

(This is just modified code from the question. I didn't test it and therefore some parameters don't have to be correct)